# cocos2d-x 3.7 Initialize with hwnd

Tags: cocos2d-x

I'm going to make some tools for game using cocos2d.
but i couldn't find any function to bind hwnd as cocos2d render window.

isn't there any functions like GLView::setHwnd or
some way to archieve what i want?

my cocos2d-x version is 3.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built in GLView is not going to support being initialized with an external hwnd.

However the Cocos2d-x director is initialzied with a user created GLView, so all you need to do is specialize GLView / GLViewImpl, create and initialize your specialized GLView and pass that when initializing Cocos:

```
auto director = Director::getInstance();
auto glView = MyGLView::create();
glView->initWithExternalHWND(_hwnd);
director->setOpenGLView(glView);
auto scene = MyScene::create();
director->runWithScene(scene);
```